Resolving ECONNREFUSED Errors in Docker Compose with Next.js, Payload CMS, and MongoDB
I'm working on a project that involves setting up a multi-container environment using Docker Compose. The setup includes a Next.js application (blueastowel), a Payload CMS backend (payload), and a MongoDB database (mongo). My goal is to have these services communicate with each other within a Docker network.
However, after running docker-compose up, I encounter ECONNREFUSED errors when the blueastowel service attempts to connect to the payload service on port 3001, and similar issues arise for other inter-service communications.

-1  | TypeError: fetch failed
blueastowel-1  |     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
blueastowel-1  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
blueastowel-1  |     at async u (/app/.next/server/pages/api/about-us.js:1:605) {
blueastowel-1  |   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3001
blueastowel-1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
blueastowel-1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
blueastowel-1  |     errno: -111,
blueastowel-1  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
blueastowel-1  |     syscall: 'connect',
blueastowel-1  |     address: '::1',
blueastowel-1  |     port: 3001
blueastowel-1  |   }
blueastowel-1  | }


Here my docker-compose.yml configuration
version: '3.8'

services:
  blueastowel:
    image: sayinmehmet47/client-blueastowel:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3001
      - PAYLOAD_API_KEY=50ab8231-770c-4fb9-9ec5-e1ce67650270
      - PAYLOAD_API_SLUG=users
      - URL=http://localhost:3000
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - payload

  payload:
    image: sayinmehmet47/payload-cms-app:latest
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo/payload-template-blank
      - PAYLOAD_SECRET=YOUR_SECRET_HERE
      - SMTP_USER=blueastowelxx@gmail.com
      - SMTP_PASS=xxx
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    command: ["--storageEngine=wiredTiger"]
    logging:
      driver: none
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

I've ensured that all services are correctly defined, and the app-network network is set up to facilitate communication between containers. Despite this, the connection issues persist.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with Docker Compose and inter-service communication?
Is the environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3001 correctly configured for this purpose?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure proper connectivity between these services in a Docker network?
Any insights or solutions to resolve these connection errors would be greatly appreciated.
After i change the environment in nextapp the app started running but just the images not fetch correctly but the texts comes
    environment:
      - PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3000
      - PAYLOAD_API_KEY=50ab8231-770c-4fb9-9ec5-e1ce67650270
      - PAYLOAD_API_SLUG=users
      - URL=http://blueastowel:3000
      - NODE_ENV=production

```
payload:3000/media/W…at%2016.20.20.jpg:1 
 GET http://payload:3000/media/WhatsApp%20Image%202024-04-24%20at%2016.20.20.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED



In your error message, you can see that it's trying to connect to address: '::1' which is localhost. So it's not picking up your NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_APP_URL variable for some reason.

@HansKilian how did you get the missing one is NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3001 not other environment variables like - URL=http://localhost:3000

Since the error message says port 3001 and that's the only environment variable with that port number, I guessed.

Which of these components run in containers, vs. running in end users' browsers?  The URLs you will need for these cases are different.  If a container is calling another then you'll need something like http://payload:3000/ using the Compose service name, but if a browser-based app is making the call it can't see these hostnames.

after changing the environment like that fetch error gone and next app started, environment:
- PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3000
- PAYLOAD_API_KEY=50ab8231-770c-4fb9-9ec5-e1ce67650270
- PAYLOAD_API_SLUG=users
- URL=http://blueastowel:3000
- NODE_ENV=production
but now even the text and image urls comes from payload app to nextjs app, the images not shown correctly
payload:3000/media/WhatsApp%20Image%202024-04-24%20at%2016.20.20.jpg:1
GET http://payload:3000/media/WhatsApp%20Image%202024-04-24%20at%2016.20.20.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

"Is the environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_APP_URL=http://payload:3001 correctly configured for this purpose? " -  depends on the purpose, i.e. how you use this variable in the code.  "Any insights" - https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/ - you need to learn how docker networks work, and always keep it mind when you make a connection - what is the source, what is the destination. Guessing will work, but only until it doesn't.
